# how do I change the ownership of vob in clearcase?

Tags: clearcase-ucm

what will be the impact of changing the ownership of vob in clearcase? Does it impact the metatdata? Is there anything else need to be changed so that users won't face any problems? how does it effect triggertype, hyperlinks and attribute type ?

Note: the group is not going to be changed but I am not sure if the existing group will be affected after changing the ownership?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use the command [`cleartool protectvob -chown ...`](https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r1m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_protectvob.htm)

It doesn't have side effect (on metadata like pvob, trtypes, attributes, ...), unless you are running it on multisite vobs.

You can use `-chown` by itself or in combination with `-chgrp`.

```
-cho/wn user
```

> Specifies a new VOB owner, who becomes the owner of all the VOB's storage pools and all of the data containers in them.

---

Note that on multisite:

> You run `protectvob -chown` or `protectvob -chgrp` on a VOB replica that preserves identities, **you must follow these steps to prevent metadata divergence among replicas in the VOB family**:
>
> 1. Stop synchronization among identities-preserving replicas in the family. Make sure that all update packets have been imported.
> 2. Run `protectvob -chown` or `protectvob -chgrp` on all identities-preserving replicas in the family. You must use the same options and arguments in each command.
> 3. Restart synchronization.
>
> (A VOB's protection with respect to privileged access by remote users is never replicated. It must be set on each replica by a privileged user logged on to the VOB server host.)

Comment: Actually, I am running it on multisite. One I change the ownership, does it need to be replicate in all site again?

Comment: @user2370590 no it doesn't change anything regarding the ownership of the stream, or its foundation baselines.